# How to find the command on the scheduled `at` job?

Tags: bash, scheduled-tasks

I have a linux server on which several `at` jobs are scheduled.
When I do `atq`, I see the usernames that have scheduled jobs and the time at which those jobs have been scheduled to run. However, I don't see what the job actually is (what script/params are being run?)

Is there a way for me to look up what is actually scheduled to run at the scheduled time, without having to wait until that time and running a `ps aux | grep username`? Ideally, I'd like to look this up without logging

Comment: suggestion serverfault.com ?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha: Good call! Please flag/close for migration

Comment: just want to link to additional answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1397964/414159 and https://serverfault.com/q/174678/290859

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Runing `atq` will give you something like this.

```
$ atq
job 1072250520.a at Wed Dec 24 00:22:00 2003
```

here `1072250520.a` is the job id. run `at -c` with this job id

```
at -c 1072250520.a
```

In my `Ubuntu 12.10`, `at -c 1` (job id `1`) gives me all the environment variables first then at the last my command.

Comment: So one command would be "at -c <job> | tac | sed -n 2p ". Here, tac reverse the order and sed -n 2p print the second line. In my case, the last line was empty.